# Convert time field H:M into integer field (minutes) in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, time

The JTable includes the time field, e.g. "01:50". I need to read this value into the integer variable. For this I´d like to convert time into minutes. For instance "01:50" should be converted into 110.

To solve the task, first I saved the time value as a String.

```
String minutS = tableModel.getValueAt(1,1).toString();
```

Secondly, I´m going to process this String and extract the integers before and after the symbol `:`. Finally I will calculate the total minutes.
Is this solution efficient? Perhaps, it´s possible to substitute it with Calendar or sth like this?

Comment: What's the actual type of the data in the table model?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think using Calendar/Date will be better than straightforward parse for this case. If your time format is indeed H:m, then I don't think you need anything more complex than this:

```
/**
 * @param s H:m timestamp, i.e. [Hour in day (0-23)]:[Minute in hour (0-59)]
 * @return total minutes after 00:00
 */
private static int toMins(String s) {
    String[] hourMin = s.split(":");
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(hourMin[0]);
    int mins = Integer.parseInt(hourMin[1]);
    int hoursInMins = hour * 60;
    return hoursInMins + mins;
}
```

Comment: @sudocodeThere's a problem in above code if given string is in 12 hrs format like 3:30pm then above code will throw numberFormat exception on line :  int mins = Integer.parseInt(hourMin[1]); 
so how to avoid this problem with above code? so basically string can be in 12 hrs format or 24 hrs format it should work !!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Look the sample below which we are using in our application

```
public static int toMinutes( String sDur, boolean bAssumeMinutes ) throws NumberFormatException {
        /* Use of regular expressions might be better */
        int iMin = 0;
        int iHr = 0;
        sDur = sDur.trim();
        //find punctuation
        int i = sDur.indexOf(":");//HH:MM
        if (i < 0) {
            //no punctuation, so assume whole thing is an number
            //double dVal = Double.parseDouble(sDur);
            double dVal = ParseAndBuild.parseDouble(sDur, Double.NaN);
            if (Double.isNaN(dVal)) throw new NumberFormatException(sDur);
            if (!bAssumeMinutes) {
                //decimal hours so add half a minute then truncate to minutes
                iMin = (int)((dVal * 60.0) + (dVal < 0 ? -0.5 : 0.5));
            } else {
                iMin = (int)dVal;
            }
        }
        else {
            StringBuffer sBuf = new StringBuffer(sDur);
            int j = sBuf.indexOf(MINUS_SIGN);
            //check for negative sign
            if (j >= 0) {
                //sign must be leading/trailing but either allowed regardless of MINUS_SIGN_TRAILS
                if (j > 0 && j < sBuf.length() -1)
                    throw new NumberFormatException(sDur);                  
                sBuf.deleteCharAt(j);
                i = sBuf.indexOf(String.valueOf(":"));
            }
            if (i > 0)
                iHr = Integer.parseInt(sBuf.substring(0, i)); //no thousands separators allowed
            if (i < sBuf.length() - 1)
                iMin = Integer.parseInt(sBuf.substring(i+1));
            if (iMin < 0 || (iHr != 0 && iMin >= 60))
                throw new NumberFormatException(sDur);
            iMin += iHr * 60;
            if (j >= 0) iMin = -iMin;
        }
        return iMin;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
String time = "1:50";
String[] split = time.split(":"); 
if(split.length == 2) { 
        long minutes = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(Integer.parseInt(split[0])) + 
                         Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        System.out.println(minutes);
    }

/* Output: 110 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Strip your input before processing it. (`commons-lang utils`)

spaces can make `NumberFormatExceptions` occur.

Answer (score 0):

Since java 1.8 the most elegant solution is probably:

`long minutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, LocalTime.parse("01:50"));`

Answer (score 0):

SudoCode's answer helped me get to the answer, one addition I made to my method though was to add logic to handle if the string input had a field for days too. (My scenario dealt with handling elapsed time).

I added an if statement to handle the logic of getting the minutes from the amount of days, and then I overrode the input string variable to hold the rest of the original string.

Expected format for this method should be 110 days 09:38:45.749298 ...

```
    private long convertElapsedTimeToMinutes(String elapsedTimeString) {

        long daysInMinutes              =   0;
        long hoursInMinutes             =   0;
        long minutes                    =   0;

        if(elapsedTimeString.contains("days")) {
            String[] daySplitStrings    =   elapsedTimeString.split("days");
            daysInMinutes               =   Long.parseLong(daySplitStrings[0].trim())*24*60;
            elapsedTimeString           =   daySplitStrings[1];
        }

        String[] hourMinuteSplitStrings =   elapsedTimeString.split(":");
        hoursInMinutes                  =   Long.parseLong(hourMinuteSplitStrings[0].trim()) * 60;
        minutes                         =   Long.parseLong(hourMinuteSplitStrings[0].trim());

        return daysInMinutes + hoursInMinutes + minutes;
    }
```