# Convert integer minutes into String "hh:mm"

Tags: java, time

I need to convert `minutes` (defined as Integer) into the following String format "hh:mm" assuming that the `startTime` is "00:00". The below-given code is what I have so far, but it does not work properly. Also it does not take into account that the `newTime` should be shifted in accordance to `startTime`. Is there any other solution?

```
String startTime = "00:00";
int minutes = 120;
double time = minutes/60;
String timeS = Double.toString(time);
String[] hourMin = timeS.split(".");
String h = hourMin[0];
String m = hourMin[1];
String newTime = "";    
newTime.concat(h+":"+m);
```

Comment: Use JodaTime. It makes date/time work actually work!

Comment: Could u provide some example?

Comment: probably should add the `homework` tag

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
String startTime = "00:00";
int minutes = 120;
int h = minutes / 60 + Integer.parseInt(startTime.substring(0,1));
int m = minutes % 60 + Integer.parseInt(startTime.substring(3,4));
String newtime = h+":"+m;
```

Comment: int h = minutes /60 + Integer.valueOf(startTime.substring(0,1));

Comment: How can I get the output "02:00"? Now it's "2:0".

Comment: You can use String.format, e.g. String.format("%02d", hours).

Comment: I found a mistake in this code. If startTime = "10:00", the code converts it to "1" instead of "10". Revisions?

Comment: this code is completely incorrect - it doesn't handle overflow from the minutes field into the hours field.

Answer (score 34):

Here you go:

```
/*Output: 02:05 */
public String fromMinutesToHHmm(int minutes) {
    long hours = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(Long.valueOf(minutes));
    long remainMinutes = min - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hours);
    return String.format("%02d:%02d", hours, remainMinutes);
}
```

**Kotlin** version

```
class DateUtils {

    companion object {

        fun fromMinutesToHHmm(minutes: Int): String {
            val hours = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(minutes.toLong())
            val remainMinutes = minutes - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hours)
            return String.format("%02d:%02d", hours, remainMinutes)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You could even shorten it to: `String.format("%02d:%02d", hours, remainMinutes);`

Comment: to convert string to minutes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909075/convert-time-field-hm-into-integer-field-minutes-in-java

Comment: This wont work if min is above 125. TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(120) should add min value.

Answer (score 6):

```
int minutes = 120;

int h = minutes / 60;
int m = minutes % 60;

String.format("%02d:%02d",h,m); // output : "02:00"
String.format("%d:%d",h,m); // output : "2:0"
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this recently for converting seconds to hours, minutes and seconds; adapt it as you please (replace "s", "m", "h" with colons, omit seconds, etc).

```
private static String getFormattedTime(int secs) {
    // int secs = (int) Math.round((double) milliseconds / 1000); // for millisecs arg instead of secs
    if (secs < 60)
        return secs + "s";
    else {
        int mins = (int) secs / 60;
        int remainderSecs = secs - (mins * 60);
        if (mins < 60) {
            return (mins < 10 ? "0" : "") + mins + "m "
                    + (remainderSecs < 10 ? "0" : "") + remainderSecs + "s";
        }
        else {
            int hours = (int) mins / 60;
            int remainderMins = mins - (hours * 60);
            return (hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours + "h "
                    + (remainderMins < 10 ? "0" : "") + remainderMins + "m "
                    + (remainderSecs < 10 ? "0" : "") + remainderSecs + "s";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

apines' answer is good but if you want to remove the warning in Android, add 'Locale' :

```
int hours = 3;
int minutes = 6;
private static final String TIME_SEPARATOR = ":";
String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d"+TIME_SEPARATOR+"%02d", hours, minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String startTime = "00:00";
int minutes = 120;

//--- counting
int hour = minutes/60;
minutes=minutes-hours*60;
String m = Integer.toString(minutes);
String h = Integer.toString(hours);
newTime=h+":"+m;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int ALLTIME_IN_MINUTES = 1444
int hour = ALLTIME_IN_MINUTES /60;
            int min = ALLTIME_IN_MINUTES %60;


            String dateStr = hour+":"+min;
            SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("H:m"); 
            Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateStr); 
            SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); 

            String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);
```

**RESULT: 
24:04**

Answer (score -2):

```
int minutes = 129;
double hoursAndMinutes = (minutes / 60)
        + (double) minutes % 60 / 100;
String hoursAndMinutesStr = new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(hoursAndMinutes).replace('.', ':');
System.out.println(hoursAndMinutesStr);
```

Comment: While technically the result is correct (because 60 < 100), this is the wrong way to approach this type of tasks. The division is logical (an hour has 60 minutes), not mathematical. Minutes are not "fractions of an hour".

Comment: Plus, please do not add answers to questions with many correct answers that already have been accepted.