# Code for adding more minutes to an "HH:MM" string

Tags: java, time

I almost finished the code, but still I need some help. This code calculates `newTime` based on adding `minutes` to `startTime`. The `minutes` might have values greater than 60. The problem is that in the current example it must output "00:10", but it outputs "23:70"...

```
    String startTime = "23:40";
    int minutes = 30;
    String[] hm = startTime.split(":");
    int h = minutes / 60 + Integer.parseInt(hm[0]);
    int m = minutes % 60 + Integer.parseInt(hm[1]);
    if (m<0) {
        if (h==0) 
            h=23;
        else 
            h = h-1;
        m = 60+m;
    }
    String newTime = String.format("%02d", h)+":"+String.format("%02d", m); 
    System.out.println(newTime);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert integer minutes into String "hh:mm"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916472/convert-integer-minutes-into-string-hhmm)

Comment: Why do you have code to handle negative minutes? does having `00:-1` make sense?  If so can you have `-1:00` ? or `-1:-1` ?

Comment: his real problem is the addition, not the string conversion

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: the code handles negative minutes, because the value of minutes might be, e.g. -30. In this case I need to properly calculate newTime by shifting it in accordance to the startTime.

Comment: @YouKuper the addition should be done after you've converted `hh:mm` into "minutes since midnight", per my answer.  That way you never get a negative number.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It's not a duplicate. It's a whole code, ie. continuation of the discussion. I might post the code in my previous topic, but I decided to open the new one, because it's slightly different.

Comment: and the actual problem is that the accepted answer to his previous question is completely incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest calculating the total number of minutes since midnight as a single value, *then* adding the desired amount, and then recalculating the resulting hours and minutes:

```
String startTime = "23:40";
int minutes = 30;

String[] hm = startTime.split(":");
int h = Integer.parseInt(hm[0]);
int m = Integer.parseInt(hm[1]);

int t = h * 60 + m;      // total minutes
t += minutes;            // add the desired offset

while (t < 0) {          // fix `t` so that it's never negative
  t += 1440;             // 1440 minutes in a day
}

int nh = (t / 60) % 24;  // calculate new hours
int nm = t % 60;         // calculate new minutes

String newTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", nh, nm);
```

You absolutely *should not* be adding your `minutes` variable to the calculation of `h` - they're incompatible units.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

...

String startTime = "23:40";
int additionalMinutes = 30;

Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( "(\\d+):(\\d+)" );
Matcher x = pat.matcher(startTime);
if (x.matches())
{
    int h = Integer.parseInt(x.group(1));
    int m = Integer.parseInt(x.group(2));

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, h);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, additionalMinutes);

    h = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    m = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    System.out.println(
            "Start: " + startTime + 
            " + " + additionalMinutes + " minutes = " +
            h + ":" + m );
}
else
{
    /* bad format */
}
```

Output: Start: 23:40 + 30 minutes = 0:10