# Formatting a number of minutes into time

Tags: java, time, formatting, hour, minute

So I have a variable time. It counts the minutes. Is there a way I can format this into minutes easily? For example, 
time = 63

would equal

1:03

and time = 605

would equal

10:05.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916472/convert-integer-minutes-into-string-hhmm

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String s = String.format("%02d:%02d", time / 60, time % 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 605);
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
}
```

Simply create a new `Calendar` and add the amount of minutes. You don't need the date part, just the time. For this reason I reset everything manually in the calendar. By using a `Calendar` you also have a lot more flexibility with other date-appropriate calculations.

Output:

> Thu Dec 05 10:05:00 CET 2013

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
int  totSec= 605;

int min=totSec/60;
int second=totSec%60;
System.out.printf("%d:%02d\n",min,second);
```

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat can render any time format you want including the above.

For the Date object you just need to set it to the number of milliseconds since epoch http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)

```
new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date(minutes * 1000 * 60))
```

The only problem with the solution above is if time is past 23:59 it will roll over.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input is always in seconds:

```
System.out.println(
    new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(
        new SimpleDateFormat("ss").parse("" + seconds)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 minsformat(305);

public void minsformat(int m){
int hour=m/60;
int s=m%60;

system.out.println(hour+":"+s);
}
```