# set the value of time to zero in stop watch using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function stop()
{
d=new Date();
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
document.getElementById("time").value = d;
}
</script>
<form>
<input type=button value="stop" onclick="stop()">
</form>
```

I want to reset the time of watch using stop button but the above code is not working.I have also tried directly putting string("00:00:00") instead of using setHours function.

Answer (score 1):

You cant set a object Date for `Element #time`, You can try:
`document.getElementById("time").value = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + getSeconds()`;

Comment: Nope. He **can** set **value** of `Element #time` to **string** representation of a date which is casted implicitly by [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) call.

Answer (score 1):

You might do something like

```
document.getElementById("time").value = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
```

check out this doc for details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx

Answer (score 1):

That method should work for setting a date object to 00:00:00, however if you're trying to implement a stopwatch, `Date` might not be the best choice as it has a lot more information than just an hour, minutes and seconds. Try incrementing a single variable every second with `setInterval`, and formatting the time using a [custom timer function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916472/convert-integer-minutes-into-string-hhmm).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function in java script for stoping the timer.

```
/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}
```